# Как выполнить сценарий в определённое время?

Tags: php

У каждого пользователя есть энергия, энергия выполняет функцию 'валюты', тоесть может кончиться, вопрос таков : как сделать чтобы каждые 5 мин. у каждого пользователя энергия пополнялась допустим на 1 ед.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть два способа: Первый способ засунуть скрипт в [крон](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), второй способ: это при каждом обращении прользователя проверять не прошло ли 5 минут после пополнения, тут надо учитывать что он долго не может обращаться к сайту и если взаимодействует с другим пользователем, то при взаимодействии надо пересчитать энергию. Я бы посоветовал первый способ.